# Network call in AppDelegate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I am making a application in Swift in which I need to load data on the first screen from server. I don't want to show the loading... on the first screen. I want to do it before I show the first screen so either in `LaunchScreen` or `AppDelegate`. I have successuffy called the API in application function of `AppDelegate` but it is going to the first screen even I have not completed the network call so how can I delay to move to first screen until my network call completes in Swift.

Comment: I would advise against holding your application in 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' because if your application doesn't finish that method in a certain amount of time (I think 10 seconds) Apple quits your application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply create first screen to be the same as the splash screen, add there the API call and when it finish, then to go to the next screen.

For more information, please show us your code in AppDelegate to give you more correct answer.

Comment: I tried to do this but for this I need to remove the LaunchScreen and if I am doing it , either it is showing the white screen or black space at top and bottom of the screen. Could you suggest me how can I get rid of Laucher Screen in swift.

Comment: You can keep the LaunScreen. After that create simple viewController with the same image as the LaunchScreen and include the API call there.
For new project you have LaunchScreen and ViewController. Add the image from the LaunchScreen to be and In the View Controller, add the API Call there. When request finish, then open ViewController2

Comment: This will show splash screen 2 times. 1 from lauchscreen and second from view controller.

Comment: Yes, this is the idea. He wants to be on the "splash screen" until the API call finish, so yes, this is what he needs.